# English version of Arnold's "Geometry and Dynamics of Galois Fields"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, reference-request

I wonder if there's an English version of [Geometry and dynamics of Galois fields by V. I. Arnol'd](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=793&option_lang=eng)?

Comment: There seems to be one referenced on the page you linked to.

Comment: is https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM2004v059n06ABEH000793/meta the english version? i couldn't view it. @ArnaudD.

Comment: I can't view it either, but it seems to be the English version.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ok I confirm it is